# Implementing an inc function with Data.Map in Haskell

Tags: haskell, lazy-evaluation

I try to reimplement a simple increment function using `Data.Map`. However eagerness makes my program hang:

```
apply :: Num a => (a, a) -> (a, a)
apply (a, b) = (a + 1, b + 1)

inc :: Map Int Int
inc = fromList (iterate apply (0, 1))
inc ! 1 -- program freezes...
```

I don't get why it freezes? Why is it eager?

Comment: It must build and organize the `Map` before looking up elements (due to the internal implementation of a `Map` as a binary search tree). `lookup 1 (iterate apply (0,1))` has no such problem, since it doesn't need to create a search tree, it just traverses the list, ignoring the infinite tail.

Comment: I made [data-inttrie](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/data-inttrie) for maps that can be lazy in this way.